# Detecting and handling race condition in the below program

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, threadpool, race-condition

I am new to multi-threading and would like to avoid a race condition that is occurring in the below code. In the release() method there is a line available.add(resource) and in the remove() method there is a line available.remove(resource). So my question is how do I synchronize the 'resource' variable to avoid this race condition?

```
    package threadpool;
    import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
    import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
    import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap;
    import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
    import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;
    import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

    public class ResourcePoolImpl<R> implements ResourcePool<R> {

    private static final String CLOSED_POOL_EXCEPTION = "Pool is closed,cannot aquire resource.";

    private static final String  RELEASE_EXCEPTION = "Unaquired resource, cannot release it.";

    private volatile boolean open = false;

    private final BlockingQueue<R> available = new LinkedBlockingQueue<R>();

    private final ConcurrentMap<R, CountDownLatch> aquired = new ConcurrentHashMap<R,  CountDownLatch>();

    public R acquire() throws InterruptedException {
    if ( !open ) { throw new IllegalStateException( CLOSED_POOL_EXCEPTION ); }
    final R resource = available.take();
    if ( resource != null ) {
        aquired.put( resource, new CountDownLatch( 1 ) );
    }
    return resource;
    }


   public R acquire( final long timeout, final TimeUnit timeUnit ) throws InterruptedException {
    if ( !open ) { throw new IllegalStateException( CLOSED_POOL_EXCEPTION ); }

    final R resource = available.poll( timeout, timeUnit );
    if ( resource != null ) {
        aquired.put( resource, new CountDownLatch( 1 ) );
    }
    return resource;
    }


    public boolean add( final R resource ) 
    {
    return available.add( resource );
    } 

    public void close() throws InterruptedException {
    open = false;
    for ( final CountDownLatch latch : aquired.values() ) {
        latch.await();
    }
    }

    public void closeNow() {
    open = false;
    }

    public boolean isOpen() {
    return open;
    }

    public void open() {
    open = true;
    }

    public void release( final R resource ) 
    {
    final CountDownLatch latch = aquired.get( resource );
    if ( latch == null ) { throw new IllegalArgumentException( RELEASE_EXCEPTION ); }
    available.add( resource );
    latch.countDown();
    }

    public boolean remove( final R resource ) throws InterruptedException 
    {   

    final CountDownLatch latch = aquired.get( resource );
    if ( latch != null ) {
        latch.await();
    }
    return available.remove( resource );
    }


    public boolean removeNow( final R resource ) {
    return available.remove( resource );
    }

 }
```

Comment: how do you know you have a race condition?

Comment: available is a BlockingQueue, which is a concurrent collection, it should not be a problem if two threads are using it.

Comment: concurrent collections only guarantee that put/get are "atomic"; the race condition may be outside this code (for example, you may be modifying the resource from two places at once...). Are you sure that the problem is in *this* code?

Comment: It would be interesting to know how you think this pool is supposed to behave.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare a

```
final Object mutex = new Object();
```

and have all methods that do read/write operations on shared collections aquire the mutex before doing the operations, or make decisions based on shared data, execute within a synchronized block:

```
synchronized (mutex) {
     // .. guaranteed single-threaded access here
     //   (for instance, contents of aquire() or release(); 
     //      also add() or any other collection access)
}
```

You can then use the simpler non-concurrent collection classes, as within the mutex-guarded areas, there cannot be any multi-threaded access.

Concurrent collections simply wrap their accesses within their own internal mutual-exclusion locks -- but the problem, as you explain in your comments, is that `aquired` and `available` may be updated independently of each other, which you definitely do not want.

Therefore: simplify your code by declaring and using a single mutex for all critical-area accesses.

Comment: in the above code for example, it may lead to a resource being added back into the pool after it has been removed if the 'release' and 'remove' methods are called at the same time by different threads, which is what i want to avoid.

Comment: What about using the mutex approach for *all* methods in the ResourcePool?. Make each of them synchronize their critical areas on a single mutex, and you can dispense with all those thread-safe collections (since the mutex will be protecting them all).

Comment: That will definitely help...but i was thinking of a better way to do it, like without having to use synchronize on all methods unnecessarily..

Comment: so you mean to say that there should not be a race condition at all in this situation? that it is handled by these collections?

Comment: After looking at java sources, those collections you use are relying on [http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.java#ReentrantLock ReentrantLocks], with very similar semantics to the built-in lock provided by synchronized(). I cannot imagine that there will be any performance difference; if there were, the single-mutex version should be faster (1 lock instead of several). Plus, you would avoid the race condition...

Comment: If you follow my answer, there would be no race. In your current code, the race exists just as you described it above in your comments.

Comment: ok..thanks for your insights...and btw do u know how to use checkthread  plugin in eclipse?